# How to encode my data to use it with an Pytorch-LSTM

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to set up a Pytorch-LSTM for an affect-analyis-problem. I am currently stuck on how I should correctly encode my data and what kind of data the LSTM expects.

I have a dataset of roughly 12000 sentences, all tagges with a specific emotion. My data is encoded as follows:

I created a seperate dataset that consists of the Part-of-Speech-Tags for every word in the sentences. The POS-Tags are one-hot-encoded:

```
0           1               83
[1,0,0..0], [0,1,0..0], ... [0,0,0..0] 
[0,0,0..1], [0,0,1..0], ... [1,0,0..0]
...
```

Every row is one sentence. All rows have a length of 84 (shorter sentences are padded with a zero-vector). The lists in each cell correspond to a specific pos-tags, they have a length of 17.

The target-dataset has the same number of rows as the dataset above, but every row only contains one list, encoding one of four emotions:

```
0           
[1,0,0,0] 
[0,0,0,1]
...
```

I am now stuck on how to instert this data (especially the pos-dataset) into the lstm. The docs say, the LSTM expects an input-dimension and output-dimension parameter. What is exactly is my input dimension here? Every sequence has a length of 84, but every item in this sequence is a list of length 17.

I've read the docs and some tutorials, however none of these seem to use a similar data structure as I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.